# Chromium dmesg Errors Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: chromium, dmesg, 14.10

> How do i fix the issue

Chromium dmesg Errors Ubuntu 14.10

```
[  443.235756] chromium-browse[3860]: segfault at 1f8 ip 00007f89021c063f sp 00007fffedad9d80 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7f8901e6d000+51c000]
[  443.600193] chromium-browse[3903]: segfault at 1f8 ip 00007ff3df93163f sp 00007fff1ca387b0 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7ff3df5de000+51c000]
[  443.802401] chromium-browse[3911]: segfault at 1f8 ip 00007f219e42963f sp 00007fffb85f9400 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7f219e0d6000+51c000]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1371834) in Ubuntu 14.10. The recommended workaround is to launch Chrome from the command line with:

```
LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 google-chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause for chromium segfaulting seems to be a bug in the intel drivers when using DRI3 and DRI2. This thread 
http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/intel-gfx/2014-July/049572.html

You could use a more recent kernel with the patches applied or wait for the patches to be included in the standard kernel.